# How to deal with many instance variables in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python and to object-oriented programming. I have a basic question on OOP using python. Suppose there is a class with some instance variables initialized. Later on, I need to add many more instance variables. I can do that with `object.attribute = value` outside the class. The code in the class does not set the attributes/variables.

Will the program not become difficult to maintain when it grows large? There would be instance variable assignments strewn everywhere in the code except inside the class. Isn't it a better idea to have those assignments in the class with `self.attribute = value`, where they can be tracked easily? What is the right approach?

Comment: Yeeees…!? I'd start with: why exactly are you assigning all those properties to your object?

Comment: If you have dynamic data to store you should consider using a dictionary.

Comment: I am creating a Person object, initialized with name and age. Then I want to add to this object attributes like postal address, email and many others, obtained as user input.

Answer (score 3):

You've reached a fork: on the left lies "in general," while on the right you can see "in specific."

In general, yes, you want your object's members to be determined by the class that defines the object. That's the whole *point* of having a class - to contain and specify similar behavior by grouping together some code (methods) and some data (instance and class variables).

In specific, however, sometimes you have a function that just needs to hang some data someplace. It may have nothing to do with the class at all - just "have I seen you before" or "here is the memoized result of a computation."

So in general, yes, you should be striving to put all your class-related data into your class. But don't get too bent out of shape if there happens to be some specific case where that doesn't happen.

**Update:**

After some comments, let's consider examples of use:

1. Use of attributes by methods:

   If you have one or more methods that use an attribute, but it's not generally available to the public, then you can delay setting the attribute until you use it:

   ```
   class Window:
       def print_text(self, text):
           if self._bg_color is None:
               self._bg_color = WHITE

           # continue...
   ```

   This attribute won't have to be in your `__init__` method, since you are taking responsibility for making sure it is set before use in your own methods.
2. Use of attributes as part of the API of the class.

   In the case where your attribute is part of the API of the class, you **cannot** control how the attribute will be used. Some dumb user is going to do whatever thing they want, and when it doesn't work, they'll be complaining about your code on Stack Overflow. ;-)

   In this case, you have two choices: (a) you can ensure that it is always set, or (b) you can intercept accesses to the member (with an `@property` method) and set it on demand.

   ```
   class Color:
       def __init__(self, r, g, b):
           self.r = r
           self.g = g
           self.b = b
           # Option (a): Ensure properties are always set:
           self.h, self.s, self.v = _compute_hsv(r, g, b)

       # Option (b): Intercept property access and compute on demand
       @property
       def h(self):
           if self._h is None:
               self._h, self._s, self._v = _compute_hsv(self.r, self.g, self.b)
           return self._h

       # likewise for s, v
   ```

Comment: But if I put all the class-related data into the class, I need to use setters and that's not recommended in python.

Comment: You can use a `property` decorator instead of Java-style getters and setters - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

Comment: You don't need to use setters: there's a difference between directly setting a known attribute, and just randomly hanging a new attribute on an object. When you set `object.attribute = value` outside the class, then nobody knows about the attribute. If you set `object.attribute = None` in your `__init__()` constructor, and then set `object.attribute = 1` somewhere else, that's okay.

Comment: @Pramod A property would be appropriate if I am doing something with the data. But for simple assignments, a property decorator for each of the many instance variables would make the class bulky.

Comment: @AustinHastings So I have to set `self.attribute = None` for, say, 20 odd attributes in the `__init__()`. Isn't there a better way because, otherwise, the code would look cluttered.

Comment: Is there some other place to set them? You could certain set the attributes in the methods that use them, if all your attributes are behind getter methods. Otherwise, how will your user know if it's okay to access the attribute?

Comment: You mean to say that there has to be some reference to the attribute inside the class, otherwise the user of the class will not know what to access. By the way, what did you mean by "if all your attributes are behind getter methods"? I believe we should not be using getters.

Comment: Right - if the class doesn't set them someplace, how will users of the class know about them, or know how to use them? As far as getter methods, you'd be surprised how many python questions appear from students whose teachers are Java programmers (and don't see any reason to change).

Comment: Thanks a lot Austin for all the comments and the post. I guess I cannot continue to comment...

Comment: Try the #python irc for live help